# Using a variable to set css property value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the height of a div based on the height of another div, which changes depending on the browser width. I wrote the following which I think makes sense but it doesn't work, so I'm not sure if there's a way to do this or not?

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {

    var newHeight = $("#div1").height();
    $("div2").css(height, newHeight);

});
```

Thanks

Comment: try `$("div2").css('height',newHeight);` - height should be quoted

Comment: + There isn't any element called `div2` correct it based on `id` or `class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code have 2 issues

1) You need to write CSS property name in quotes.

2) You are missing ID selector for div2

```
$("#div2").css('height',newHeight);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `height` of an element using [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
$("#div2").css('height', newHeight + 'px');
// ^           ^      ^            ^^^^^^^
```

You can also use [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to set the height of an element.

```
$("#div2").height(newHeight);
```